# Difference between lexical and syntactic errors in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have the following java class that I need to find the possible errors and distinguish between lexical, semantic and syntactic. I have put the errors on the side of each one but I am not sure what is the difference between them and if I identified them right.

```
class Part {
    private int number;
    private String name;
    private int quantity;

    public Part(int number, String name, int quantity){
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Part(int number, string name){ // Semantic Error
       this(number, name, 0);
    }

    public Part(){
        this(0, 'No Name'); // Lexical Error
    }

    public void decreaseQuantity(int amount){
        quantity =- amount;
    }

    public int getName(){ //Semantic error
        return name;
    }

    public int getnumber(){
        return number;
    }

    public int getQuantity(){
        return quanity; // Semantic error
    } // Syntatic Error(this was a missing bracket)
}
```

Comment: Lexical deals with words themselves, semantic deals with the _meaning_ of words.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `enum` to distinguish them:

```
public enum ErrorType {LEXICAL, SEMANTIC, SYNTACTIC}
```

And add property in your class:

```
class Part {
    private ErrorType errorType; 
    // other properties and methods}
}
```

Comment: Trying now Ashot, thanks. I read a lot but not sure still what is the main difference.

Comment: If there is more difference between types, you can create classes for each one - with one super class/interface.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question? This is a homework-style question where you identify errors. It's not about how to represent errors in code.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi what do you mean? This is just a approach, is it bad thing?

Comment: The question is how do you know if an error is lexical or semantic. This does not answer that question.